# Checkout error on magento 2.3.2 after upgrade

Tags: checkout, jquery, magento2.3.2

i had upgraded magento version to 2.3.2 and on checkout page i am getting following error

```
payment.js:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: getPaymentInformation is not defined
    at UiClass.navigate (payment.js:50)
    at UiClass.initialize (payment.js:39)
    at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
    at new UiClass (class.js:49)
    at Object.initComponent (layout.js:137)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
    at Object.deferred.<computed> (jquery.js:3461)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
```

Comment: Possibly redeploy your static content see if that fixed the issue also rerun setup:di:compile but before you do any of these make sure your the the content of generation/ var/di var/view_processed which should give you a fresh slate on deployment

Comment: i tried above option also still has same issue

Comment: Which gateway are you using? have you tried disabling the gateway and enabling alternative one just to test? may be the extension is incompatible with 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

This error results from invalidly configured payment method in admin. However I can't tell you how to fix yet as I don't know which payment method you are using.

Please go to stores => configuration => sales => payment method to check this information